# Pandas finding pairs in grouby function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a huge dataframe in pandas that has following format:

```
period  from_       to_        value
2020-07 Jonny       Karl       15.00
2020-08 Matt        Jonny      5.00
2020-08 Matt        Karl       5.00
2020-08 Matt        Karl       10.00
2020-08 Jonny       Matt       10.00
```

Where I have values of one person need to pay to another person by a period of the year. The name of those persons repeat themselves over the dataset.

So I want to see per period of year the values one person owes to another person. For that, I can simply use:

```
sum_df = df.groupby([ "period", "from_", "to_"]).agg({"value": 'sum'})
```

But is here that lies my question, because I'm trying to figure out a performative way to do this aggregating function where it could "identify":
if `person A` owes 5$ to `person B`. and `person B` owe 10$ to `person A`. It should return that `person B` owe for that period 5$ to `person A`. Resulting in the following dataframe:

```
period  from_       to_        value
2020-07 Jonny       Karl       15.00
2020-08 Matt        Karl       15.00
2020-08 Jonny       Matt       5.00
```

Someone could give me a direction in which I could follow to reach that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is very tricky. First [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) the dataframe from the groupby by itself, but comparing the columns `from_` for `to_` and `to_` for `from_`.
Subtract the values from the `value` and `value_y` columns that were generated and save this in a variable. With this variable it is possible to update the column in the original DF using [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html)

```
df1 = df.groupby(['period','from_','to_'])['value'].sum().reset_index()

temp = df1.reset_index().merge(df1, 
                               left_on=['period', 'from_', 'to_'], 
                               right_on=['period', 'to_', 'from_'], 
                               suffixes=['', '_y'])

temp['value'] = temp['value'] - temp['value_y']
temp = temp[['index','period', 'from_', 'to_', 'value']]

temp.set_index('index', inplace=True)
df1.update(temp)

df1.head()
    period  from_   to_     value
0   2020-07 Jonny   Karl    15.0
1   2020-08 Jonny   Matt    5.0
2   2020-08 Matt    Jonny   -5.0
3   2020-08 Matt    Karl    15.0
```

here you can decide what to do with the data of people who owe nothing to anyone. If they are deleted from the DF, or set the column `value` to zero

```
#remove rows where value is equal to or less than zero
df1.loc[df1['value'] > 0]
#output:
    period  from_   to_     value
0   2020-07 Jonny   Karl    15.0
1   2020-08 Jonny   Matt    5.0
3   2020-08 Matt    Karl    15.0

#setting the value column to zero where it is negative
df1.loc[df1['value'] < 0, 'value'] = 0
#output:
    period  from_   to_     value
0   2020-07 Jonny   Karl    15.0
1   2020-08 Jonny   Matt    5.0
2   2020-08 Matt    Jonny   0.0
3   2020-08 Matt    Karl    15.0
```

Comment: WOWWWWW. What a trick and genius answer! Realy!!! You nailed it. It exploded my limited bounds! haha Super awesome!!! Someday I want to reach that level of abstraction! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Let me post a solution here for you to explore. I'll add explanation later.

```
pairs = df[['from_','to_']]
sorted_pairs = np.sort(df[['from_','to_']].values, axis=1)

(df['value'].mul(np.where((pairs==sorted_pairs).all(1), 1, -1))
     .groupby([df['period'],sorted_pairs[:,0], sorted_pairs[:,1]])
     .sum()
     .reset_index(name='value')
)
```

Output:

```
    period level_1 level_2  value
0  2020-07   Jonny    Karl   15.0
1  2020-08   Jonny    Matt    5.0
2  2020-08    Karl    Matt  -15.0
```

Comment: Amazing answer! I loved that way of thinking. Very pythonic! However I'll stick with the other answer because it suits more to the other dependencies I have in my project! Thank you so much though!!